# How do containers/layouts reposition their children?

Tags: qt, user-interface, gtk, wxwidgets

I'm working on a simple widget system, and I'm implementing some containers right now.

Here's the situation I find myself in:

- I have a `Widget` base class, a `Container` class, which is a widget that can contain other widgets, and several widget sub classes like `Button`.
- I have two types of container: `Container` itself, which positions children absolutely, and `Box`, which will stack widgets next to each other, either horizontally or vertically.
- Each widget draws itself at x=0, y=0. Therefore, containers need to add an offset to the drawing context before the widgets are told to draw themselves.
- Each widget does its own hit testing based on its x/y position.

So far, it works fine. But it falls apart now that I'm implementing `Box`: What I do is that I overwrite the `draw`function inherited from `Container` to draw them all in next to each other, instead of based on their x/y position. Quite simple.

But event handling is totally off now, as the widget's x/y position has become meaningless.

I think I have two options:

1. Have the widget do hit testing at position x=0, y=0, like drawing. Then recalculate the mouse position to match that in `Container`.
2. Make each layout set x/y for its children, and make children draw themselves at their x/y position again. No more offsets for the drawing context

The first one is a bit ugly, I think. The second one is pretty complicated to implement, since I need to react to position changes in widgets.

How to other widget systems like Qt, Gtk and wxWidgets generally tackle this? I've looked at the source of some of these, but can't quite figure that out, it's too sophisticated. I don't have any resizing or packing issues to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement your own layout system. You should expect it to be difficult.
I would advise against the first method. The x,y coordinates of a widget are not only used by the widgets themselves, but by anyone outside of the container who wants to do something with the widget.

The second solution is what I've chosen to implement custom widgets made of several smaller widgets and it's not that hard to put together if you don't want too many features.
Just get the widgets when they are added to your container, set their position to the current free spot, and move on to the next.